# Search Display Template code no longer able to access CurrentItem.UniqueId

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template

I have a SharePoint Online site that uses some custom Search [Display Templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/display-template-reference-in-sharepoint-server) to display content from Document Libraries and Picture Libraries.  The JavaScript code had been running fine for a couple of years. However, within the past few days, several properties of the ctx.CurrentItem object have started returning *null*.  Namely:

- ctx.CurrentItem.UniqueId
- ctx.CurrentItem.WebId
- ctx.CurrentItem.SiteId

Does anyone know what might have changed in SharePoint Online recently to cause this?  Were these properties deprecated?

Thanks!